# How to use accept function for droppable with more than a specific element?

Tags: jquery

I have elements of draggable and droppable. Than I want that some of them will be accepted in some of the droppables and some not (the bottom can be dropped in the up and the other way), I want to sort them by data attribut that I check if it has the specific value for each matching between draggable and droppable element.
I'm trying to do it with the accept function but I don't know how to work with it with no specific element.

the html elemnts are these:

```
<img  data-hand="hand-bottom-left" src="images\bottom-left-close.jpg">
<img  data-hand="hand-bottom-left" src="images\bottom-left-close.jpg">
<br>
<img data-hand="hand-up-left-close"  src="images\up-left-close.jpg">
<img data-hand="hand-up-left-close"  src="images\up-left-close.jpg">
```

this is the js code:

```
$("[data-hand*='hand']" ).draggable({
revert: true

});

$( "[data-hand*='hand']" ).droppable({
accept:function({
    if ($(img).attr('data-hand').indexOf('bottom') > -1)
    {
    // I don't know how to go on and if i'm in the right way    
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

If you want a droppable to be only able to accept items from a different category, then you just need to check if the dragging item and the target droppable has a different `data-hand` value.

I added a jsFiddle for demo. An alert should popup only after the drop was accepted.

```js
$("[data-hand*='hand']")
   .draggable({
          revert: true
    })
   .droppable({
          accept: function(e){
             return $(e).attr('data-hand') !== $(this).attr('data-hand');
          }, 
          drop: function(){
             alert('dropped');
          }
    });
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div data-hand="hand-up-left-close">1</div>
<div data-hand="hand-up-left-close">2</div>
<br>
<div data-hand="hand-bottom-left">3</div>
<div data-hand="hand-bottom-left">4</div>
```

Accept option expects either a `selector` referring to the acceptable element, or a `function` that returns a boolean value to test whether the target element should be accepted.

In your case, you can write the function like this:

```
accept: function(){ 
     return $(this).attr('data-hand').indexOf('bottom') > -1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to put it in my code and it didn't work. And also I want that the bottom elements will be droppable for the up, and the up elements will be droppable for the bottom. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @UrielOfir I updated my answer. Let me know which part of the code you think is not working.

Comment: @ Eliellel it's still doesn't work. I decided to change my code and write droppable function to each element with his options, and not all together.

Comment: @UrielOfir I'm afraid you need to be more specific than saying it doesn't work.. Start from playing around the jsfiddle demo I put up there, tell me what is the feature you are looking for but the code failed to achieve?

Comment: Thank you. Eventually it worked. But I changed the whole code so I don't know what was the problem and what was the solution